# Stop OS X from hiding menus when clicking the separator/spacer

Tags: macos, mac, context-menu

Is it possible in the OS or with a third party app/plugin to stop menus (right click etc) from hiding when you click the space between two items?

For example, if you click the Apple menu in the top left of the screen, and click between **About This Mac** and **System Preferences** the menu disappears.

I obviously never played COD as evident by my terrible mouse skills, because I frequently click these little spacers, and it hides the menu, meaning I need to reopen the menu to show it.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have the same problem (both with separators and disabled items) and haven't been able to find a solution, but haven't asked here either so hopefully someone will know of something.

Comment: You could use the down arrow & Enter key - then you can't miss ;-)

Comment: Hmm they seem to have fixed this in macOS Sierra!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to macOS Sierra or macOS High Sierra and clicks on menu item separators and clicks on disabled menu items will not cause the menu to hide.